# Is it possible to store temporary values of hovered elements and compare those values in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In an AngularJS directive, is it possible to keep track of the index of an `li` element, and store that index value so it can be compared with the index value of the next hovered `li` element?

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('projectsHover', function($animate) {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.css('position', 'absolute');

        // offset each by 500px
        var liTotal = element.parent().children().length;
        for (var i = 0; i < liTotal; i++ ) {
            element.css('left', i * 500 + 'px');
        }

        element.on("mouseover", mouseover);

        var oldHoveredElement;

        function mouseover(){
            $animate.addClass(element, 'hovering');

            // do some animation code here ...

            oldHoveredElement = element; // doesn't keep track of the old element; always overwrites with currently hovered element. How can I store and reference the previously hovered on element?

            console.log("oldHoveredElement.index(): ", oldElement.index());
            console.log("element.index(): ", element.index());

            if (oldHoveredElement.index() > element.index()) {
                console.log("oldHoveredElement has a larger index value");
            }
        }
    }
  };
});
```

**Template:**

```
<ul>
    <li projects-hover ng-repeat="project in projects" index="$index">
        <div class="project-blurb">
            <a>{{ project.title }}</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: get the index before reassigning `oldHoveredElement`

Comment: I have a feeling that you are over complicating this. Can you please describe what you are trying to achieve? I think you can use 'onMouseOut' event instead of keeping track of indexes.

Comment: There should be 3 animations that take place on the lis that are horizontally arranged. The first animation: the li that is hovered on should have its width increased. 2nd animation: the li with a lower index should move to the left. 3rd animation: the li with higher index should move to right.

Comment: I'm new to angular ... wondering if I need to implement a controller in the directive to manage the variables? Or is there a simpler "Angular" way to go?

Comment: can store variables right in the link function. It's simply a matter of getting your logic right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up making a directive in the parent `ul` to manage the old and current index passed in from the children `li`.

```
    <ul projects-hover-manager>
        <li project-hover ng-repeat="project in projects track by $index" ng-class="setClassName()">
            <div class="project-blurb">
                <a>{{ project.title }}</a>
                <div ng-bind-html="project.description"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

app.directive('projectsHoverManager', function(){
    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
        var before, current, after;
        var oldIndex, className;

        this.giveClassName = function(index) {

            if (oldIndex == index) {
                console.log("oldIndex: ", oldIndex);
                console.log("index: ", index);
                console.log("currentLi");
                className ="currentLi";

            } else if (oldIndex > index) {
                console.log("oldIndex: ", oldIndex);
                console.log("index: ", index);
                console.log("beforeLi");
                className = "beforeLi";

            } else if (oldIndex < index) {
                console.log("oldIndex: ", oldIndex);
                console.log("index: ", index);
                console.log("afterLi");
                className = "afterLi";
            }
            oldIndex = index;
            return className;
        };
    }
  };
});

app.directive('projectHover', function($animate) {
    return {
        require: '^projectsHoverManager',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, projectsHoverManagerCtrl) {
            element.css('position', 'absolute');

        // offset each by 500px
        var liTotal = element.parent().children().length;
        for (var i = 0; i < liTotal; i++ ) {
            element.css('left', i * 500 + 'px');
        }

        // element.css('left', '500px');
        element.on("mouseover", mouseover);

        function mouseover(){

            $animate.addClass(element, 'hovering');

            // animation code ...

            projectsHoverManagerCtrl.giveClassName(element.index());

            scope.$apply();

        }
    };
});
```